# Determine if Git working directory is clean from a script

Tags: shell-script, git

I have a script which runs `rsync` with a Git working directory as destination. I want the script to have different behavior depending on if the working directory is clean (no changes to commit), or not. For instance, if the output of `git status` is as below, I want the script to exit:

```
git status
Already up-to-date.
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
Everything up-to-date
```

If the directory is not clean then I would like it to execute some more commands.

How can I check for output like the above in a shell script?

Comment: Would checking a status from last command help here? ($?)

Comment: Could you give more details please? What is the main idea for your script?

Comment: @tachomi I added the context in the edit

Comment: you could just assume it's not clean and do a `git reset --hard origin/branch` if that is what you are going for... like if you are trying to cleanup after compiling something, etc.

Comment: @SnakeDoc You could, but I assume that the inverse case would be more common, i.e. exit if the working directory is dirty to avoid mangling local changes. Considering both case would make question more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 320, accepted):

Parsing the output of `git status` is a bad idea because the output is intended to be human readable, not machine-readable. There's no guarantee that the output will remain the same in future versions of Git or in differently configured environments.

[UVVs comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155046/if-then-in-shell-script#comment253463_155046) is on the right track, but unfortunately the return code of `git status` doesn't change when there are uncommitted changes. It does, however, provide the [`--porcelain`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html) option, which causes the output of `git status --porcelain` to be formatted in an easy-to-parse format for scripts, *and* will remain stable across Git versions and regardless of user configuration.

We can use empty output of `git status --porcelain` as an indicator that there are no changes to be committed:

```
if [ -z "$(git status --porcelain)" ]; then 
  # Working directory clean
else 
  # Uncommitted changes
fi
```

If we do not care about untracked files in the working directory, we can use the [`--untracked-files=no`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html) option to disregard those:

```
if [ -z "$(git status --untracked-files=no --porcelain)" ]; then 
  # Working directory clean excluding untracked files
else 
  # Uncommitted changes in tracked files
fi
```

To make this more robust against conditions which *actually* cause `git status` to fail without output to `stdout`, we can refine the check to:

```
if output=$(git status --porcelain) && [ -z "$output" ]; then
  # Working directory clean
else 
  # Uncommitted changes
fi
```

It's also worth noting that, although `git status` does not give meaningful exit code when the working directory is unclean, `git diff` provides the [`--exit-code`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) option, which makes it behave similar to the [diff](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) utility, that is, exiting with status `1` when there were differences and `0` when none were found.

Using this, we can check for unstaged changes with:

```
git diff --exit-code
```

and staged, but not committed changes with:

```
git diff --cached --exit-code
```

Although `git diff` can report on untracked files in submodules via appropriate arguments to [`--ignore-submodules`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html), unfortunately it seems that there is no way to have it report on untracked files in the actual working directory. If untracked files in the working directory are relevant, `git status --porcelain` is probably the best bet.

Comment: ughhh `git status --porcelain` will exit with code 0 even if there are changes not staged for commit and untracked files.

Comment: I was interested in determining ahead of time if `git stash` would do anything (it doesn't output a useful return code). I had to add `--ignore-submodules` as otherwise `git status` would indicate submodule changes which `git stash` ignores.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: I observed the same. But then checked what `if [ -z` was doing. The `-z` means that if the following string is empty, the if evaluates to `true`. In other words, if this `git status --porcelain` results in no string, the repo is clean. If not, it lists the modified/added/removed files and is no longer an empty string. The `if` then evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Use `git diff --quiet --exit-code` if you just want the exit code

Comment: I find `git diff --quiet` (which per the man page also implies `--exit-code`) returns `256` if there are changes, `33024` if not in a git tree, and various other high numbers for different error conditions. I wonder if the value `256` can be relied upon through different versions of git?

Comment: @Rodney I don't think the return value of a process goes over 255 on Unix systems. Are you on Windows?

Comment: @iBug I can't reproduce that behaviour now, in bash or python. I get `1` for changes, higher numbers for error conditions. I'll delete that comment. But, as noted elsewhere the biggest problem with `git diff --quiet` is it doesn't show untracked files *or* staged but uncommitted changes.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer! Based on this answer, I made a more-granular version which differentiates between "`git status` failed", "working tree is clean" (no uncommitted changes), and "working tree is dirty" (has uncommitted changes), here: [Shell script to programmatically interpret the output of git status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73284206/4561887)

Comment: Can you explain why saving the `output` variable makes this more robust? Is it something to do with Bash's subshell behavior? I don't see when it would behave differently.

Answer (score 56):

Use:

```
git update-index --really-refresh
git diff-index --quiet HEAD
```

The return code reflects the state of the working directory (0 = clean, 1 = dirty). Untracked files are ignored.

Comment: Returns 0 when there are untracked files in the current directory.

Comment: If files had been touched/overwritten but are otherwise identical to the index, you need to first run `git update-index --refresh` before `git diff-index HEAD`.  More info: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34807971/1407170

Comment: @AdamParkin I just add all files with `git add .` before issuing it. Usually it's the way to use it in a script

Comment: This is great. Note that a return/exit code of non-zero is also interpreted as an 'error', which if you're in a script with [set -e](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) then your script will exit if 'dirty'. This can be avoided by doing `set +e` before the call to `git`, and adding `set -e` again after you've evaluated `$?`.

Comment: @orionelenzil a better option than using `set +e` is to put to use [the 2nd sentence](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#:~:text=the%20shell%20does%20not%20exit%20if%20the%20command%20that%20fails%20is%20part%20of%20the%20command%20list%20immediately%20following%20a%20while%20or%20until%20keyword%2C%20part%20of%20the%20test%20in%20an%20if%20statement%2C%20part%20of%20any%20command%20executed%20in%20a%20%26%26%20or%20%7C%7C%20list%20) in the doc you linked to. You even used it [in your answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/509453/9745)

Comment: @BrunoBronosky - Excellent point, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Minor extension to [André's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/253060/andr%C3%A9-van-herk) excellent [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394674/34277).

Untracked files are ignored.

```
git update-index --really-refresh
if git diff-index --quiet HEAD
then
  GIT_MODS="clean"
else
  GIT_MODS="dirty"
fi
```

If you want to avoid putting stuff in stdout, you may want to add `>> /dev/null` or similar on the `update-index` line.

Comment: Accessing `$?` is inferior to just using `if` directly on the command: `if ! git diff-index --quiet HEAD; then`. However, this method is not 100% reliable, suffering from a potential false-positive "dirty" result if you don't first run `git update-index --really-refresh`. To see this in action `touch` an existing committed file to update only its date, and then you'll see a non-zero return code from `diff-index` even though there are actually no changes.

Comment: Subtle. Thank you; edited.

Comment: I get the `diff-index`, but exactly what is `update-index` need for?

Answer (score 5):

If you just want a 0 or 1 process exit code, then you can just run a [test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_(Unix)) outside of an `if-then` block.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$(git status --porcelain)" ]
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

test -z "$(git status --porcelain)"
```

Example:

```
$ test -z "$(git status --porcelain)"
$ echo $?
0

$ echo 'hello world' > fish.txt
$ test -z "$(git status --porcelain)"
$ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this kind of test

```
TEST=$(git status --porcelain|wc -l)
if [ 0 -eq $TEST ]; then
   echo "No changes"
else
   echo "Changes"
fi
```

Comment: There is no need to count the number of lines, just to determine if *any* lines were produced, so piping to another program is wasteful and doesn't express intent well. Please see Thomas Nyman's answer for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `git describe --broken --dirty --all` and checking the result to see if it ends in `-dirty` (or `-broken`); then, using the same thing on any submodules with `git submodule foreach ...` ?

This requires a modern (version  >= 3.x) of `bash` as I understand it, it also does not investigate untracked files - which is not unreasonable in my opinion (at least they shouldn't be clobbered if a difference branch is checked out!) - note that it only returns a zero exit status if everything is clean:

```
#!/bin/bash

RESULT=$(git describe --broken --dirty --all)
STATUS="clean"
if [[ "${RESULT}" =~ broken$ ]]; then
    # Bail out now, in case it is not safe to look for sub-modules
    echo "Main repository is broken."
    exit -3
elif [[ "${RESULT}" =~ dirty$ ]]; then
    echo "Main repository is dirty - not checking any submodules."
    STATUS="dirty"
    exit -1
else
    git submodule foreach --recursive --quiet 'RESULT=$(git describe --broken --dirty --all) 
        if [[ "${RESULT}" =~ broken$ ]]; then
            echo "Submodule ${name} is broken."
            exit -3
        elif [[ "${RESULT}" =~ dirty$ ]]; then
            echo "Submodule ${name} is dirty."
            STATUS="dirty"
        else
            echo "Submodule ${name} is clean."
        fi' 
    echo -n "Main repository is clean "
    if [ "${STATUS}" = "dirty" ]; then
        echo "- but at least one submodule is dirty."
        exit -2
    else
        echo "- and so are any submodules."
    fi
fi
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`git status --short` can be used for that.  It prints list of modified or untracked files without clutter.  Empty output means no changes.

```bsh
if [ -z "$(git status --short)" ]; then
  echo "Clean"
else
  echo "Dirty"
fi
```

Output is almost identical (if not identical) like in `git status --porcelain` suggested in other answers, but `--short` is more straightforward and easier to remember.  On the other hand, `--porcelain` API will keep its behavior across Git versions and configurations (see [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#Documentation/git-status.txt---porcelainltversiongt)) which is an important factor, too.